# Gem list not listing all installed gems

Tags: macos, rubygems

I run a `sudo gem list` or `gem query --local`, and it only lists a portion of the gem's installed.

For instance ruby-debug is installed, I'm using it to debug stuff...but it doesn't show up in the gem list.

I've tried to run `gem update —system` and it doesn't do anything.

Note: if I then run a `sudo gem install ruby-debug` it installs successfully and is then displayed in a gem list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has happened to me in the past when installing rubygems via macports/apt-get and then upgrading it either manually or with update --system.  You should be able to find your original list of installed gems somewhere under /opt/local; use locate to find it.  You can find the new path with locate as well, but I didn't have any luck when I tried to move the them folders to the new location...so you need to manually re-install all the gems.